\nocite{*} causes Undefined control sequence at \printbibliography
Using \nocite{*} leads to a Undefined control sequence at \printbibliography. If I define a specific source, such as \nocite{axford-1961}, it compiles without issue.
Compiler: XeLaTeX
I thought it might have had to do with documentclass, but when I switch from \documentclass{book} to \documentclass{article} it just generates a completely empty bibliography.
An absolutely stripped down version of the .tex document:
\documentclass[letterpaper,spanish, 12pt]{book}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear, natbib=true, url=false, sorting=nty]{biblatex}  
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}

\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}

% ---------------- BIBLIOGRAFÍA -----------------------------------------

\date{August 2024}
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}

%------------------------------------------
% BIBLIOGRAFIA
%------------------------------------------

\printbibliography

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Bibliografía}
\nocite{*}
\backmatter
\end{document}


sample from .bib file:
@article{axford-1961,
    title        = {A unifying theory of high-latitude geophysical phenomena and geomagnetic storms},
    author       = {given-i=WI, given={W. I.}, family=Axford and given-i=CO, given={C. O.}, family=Hines},
    volume       = 39,
    number       = 10,
    pages        = {1433--1464},
    doi          = {10.1139/p61-172},
    url          = {https://doi.org/10.1139/p61-172},
    date         = {1961-10-01},
    journaltitle = {Canadian journal of physics}
}

Relevant excerpt from raw logs:
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load language 'english'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'english.lbx' found.
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/english.lbx
File: english.lbx 2024/03/21 v3.20 biblatex localization (PK/MW)
)
Package biblatex Info: XeTeX detected.
(biblatex)             Assuming input encoding 'utf8'.
Package biblatex Info: Automatic encoding selection.
(biblatex)             Assuming data encoding 'utf8'.
\openout3 = `output.bcf'.

Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliographic data...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'output.bbl' found.
(./output.bbl)
Package biblatex Info: Reference section=0 on input line 11.
Package biblatex Info: Reference segment=0 on input line 11.
[1

] [2

]
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <12> on input line 18.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <8> on input line 18.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <6> on input line 18.
[3]
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \ssr 
                
l.19 


Welcome to TeX.SE. What happens if you execute \nocite{*} before \printbibliography?

Thanks! Unfortunately, same problem.
I just tried with a minimized .bib file and it compiled file, so I'm thinking there may be an error there. Unsure exactly what and not keen to test each entry one at a time.

what you describe sounds quite expected that citing specific entries works but if you use * then all entries get used and presumably one of them is using an undefined command \ssr

Holy crap. I can't believe I missed that. Yes! Somehow the abbreviation for Space Science Review was turned into a command. Thank you so much for the second look.

As pointed out by David Carlisle, that undefined \ssr command at the end was hiding in a couple of my bibliography entries.
Thank you all for the second look!
